# Front-end: underscore.js or async.js via browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

So if you're a back-end node.js dev, you'll know about the awesome lib called [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) .

If you're a front-end dev, you'll know about the awesome lib called [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

---

Now the thing is, both of these libs tend to provide similar features to some extent.

So the question is, does it make sense to use async on the front end using [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) ?

Comment: You should also check out nimble (http://caolan.github.com/nimble/) it combines the best of both into one tiny file.

Comment: nimble does not seem pretty much maintained!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Underscore` is a utility library that provides some useful functions like `each`, `map` and `reduce`. But, all of these work synchronously. For example

```
var results = _.map([1,2,3], function(value, index, list) {
  return value * 2;
});

console.log(results);
```

Output:
[2, 4, 6]

If you notice, the `console.log(results)` statement gets called only after the `_.map()` function is fully executed and the results returned. This is the typical synchronous style of programming that you use in browser scripting.

On the server, where `Node.js` is the king, synchronous programming as above is harmful to the event loop. There, asynchronous style of programming is preferred. Take a look at the same `map` method using the `async` library.

```
async.map([1,2,3],
        function mapper(item, callback) {
            callback(null, item * 2);
        },
        function(error, results) {
            console.log(results);
        }
);
```

Output:
[2, 4, 6]

If you notice, it doesn't return the mapped array as return value, instead the mapped array is passed to the callback function and the `console.log(results)` is used to print the results inside of the callback.

One side effect of this style of programming is that the `iterator` function gets called in parallel, not in serial order thereby enabling way more scalability if the iterator function uses any I/O.

So, even though some of the functions offered by `async` library is similar to the one's offered by `Underscore`, they are for different purposes as demonstrated above. Now, the decision of which ones to use depends on your application requriements and programming style.

Comment: I was not aware of the synchronous differences! Thank you mate :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [async readme](https://github.com/caolan/async) it can be used directly in the browser. Using browersify seems excessive.

Comment: The two libraries are pretty different. Underscore is a functional toolbelt while async allows you to write cleaner asynchronous code without as many spaghetti callbacks.